# How to divide by 0 in c++

Tags: c++

I have made a calculator in c++ and I am trying to check when the user tries to divide by 0 for it to give an error. Is there an example of this anywhere.

This is what I have got so far

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    char symb;

    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "Enter the symbol: ";
    cin >> symb;

    cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    cin >> num2;

    int calculation;
    if (symb == '+') {
        calculation = num1 + num2;
    }
    else if (symb == '-') {
        calculation = num1 - num2;
    }else if (symb == '/'){
        calculation = num1 / num2;
    }
    else if (symb == '*') {
        calculation = num1 * num2;
    }
    else if (calculation == 0 ) {
        throw error;
    }
    else {
        cout << "wrong symbol";

    }
    cout << calculation;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're already checking if the symbol is /, and dividing by 0 means num2 is zero... not sure what you need help with?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You also should rename `cacluation` as `calculation`…

Comment: @Obsidian: Do feel empowered to edit a question with typos that don't change the nature of the question.

Comment: Only Chuck Norris can divide by zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At very first, you have undefined behaviour in your programme:

```
int cacluation; // uninitialised!
if (...) { }
else if (...) { }
// ...
else if (cacluation == 0) // <- (!)
{
    // ...
}
```

If all those previous checks failed (i. e. user did not enter a valid symbol), you are now evaluating the uninitialised variable `calculation`!

Apart from, this check would be incorrect anyway, assume user entering `1 + -1` or `1 - 1`...

What you indeed need to do is checking the divisor *before* executing the calculation, and you only do so if user actually wants to divide:

```
// ...
else if (symb == '/')
{
    // check BEFORE calculation:
    if(num2 == 0)
    {
        // appropriate error handling, e. g. print some error message
    }
    else
    {
        cacluation = num1 / num2;
    }
}
```

Finally, you'd yet need to avoid printing out the invalid result. A pretty simple way would be replacing the assignment to `calculation` variable with outputting the value directly:

```
else
{
    std::cout << num1 / num2; // analogously in all other branches
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(The behaviour of a division by zero is undefined in standard C++, although IEEE754 does define the behaviour for floating point types.)

If you use `throw`, then you also need to provide a corresponding `catch`.

But as you don't need to do that in this case (you are already issuing errors to the console) a simple

```
if (!num2){
    std::cerr << "division by zero";
}
```

in the part of the code that computes the division would be sufficient.

Your branch `else if (calculation == 0)` is also a bug since there's nothing to initialise `calculation`, but my fix removes the need for that.

Comment: Stylistically I would much prefer `num2 != 0`, even if `!num2` is exactly equivalent.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Funny how folk get so trenchant. I *loathe* `num2 != 0`. What are your feelings on `(num != 0) == true`?

Comment: My feelings are "write what you want to express". If I want to check whether a mathematical integer is different from zero, `num != 0` is the direct translation of that. If I want to check whether some value is truthy or falsy I use `!value`. The former implies the latter here, so the latter is is conceptually one step more _to me_, which is not worth saving a few characters over. I won't go into the `== true` or the "trenchant" because I have no intention to be combative about this obviously opinion-based stylistic issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (symb == '/'){
    if (num2 ==0)
        cout<<"Mathematical error";
    else
        calcluation = num1 / num2;
}
```

Comment: A bit too short: `std::cout << calculation;` following the if/else chain will yield undefined behaviour, as calculation is not initialised if such error occurs. Apart from, *if* it occurs, we wouldn't want to output any value any more anyway...

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Just check if `num2` is equals to zero if the char is `/`. You have an runtime exception on row

```
else if (symb == '/'){
   cacluation = num1 / num2;
}
```

if num2 is zero.

This is wrong:

```
else if (cacluation == 0 ) {
     throw error;
}
```

It could be zero divided by anything but zero. It will be a zero as an answer. You are wrong.

Comment: No, there is no guarantee of a runtime exception. You have undefined behavior when dividing integers by zero.

Comment: Yes, you are correct for C++. My bad, but the other is right.